# Add to Favorite a Button inside a StackPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a problem and nothing come to my mind how to solve this.

I need to add a button to Favorites in a StackPanel, the problem is that the button is pressed on other page that is StackPanel declared and I can't Add button to it's Children.
So, I have 2 pages: MainPage.xaml and PlayerPage.xaml .

In MainPage I keep a StackPanel with Buttons like:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="mainStack"  >
  <Button x:Name="but1" Click="Button2_Click" Tag="/videos/video1.mp4" Content="Play Video 1" />
  <Button x:Name="but2" Click="Button2_Click" Tag="/videos/video2.mp4" Content="Play Video 2" />
  <Button x:Name="but3" Click="Button2_Click" Tag="/videos/video3.mp4" Content="Play Video 3" />
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel x:Name="favoriteStack"  >
  <!-- Here need to be added favorite videos when user press Add to fav button! -->
</StackPanel>
```

.cs

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(
        new Uri("/PlayerPage.xaml?path=" +
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode((sender as Button).Tag.ToString()),
                UriKind.Relative));
}
```

In PlayerPage.xaml :

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement1"
              MediaOpened="mediaElement1_MediaOpened"
              MediaFailed="mediaElement1_MediaFailed"
              MediaEnded="mediaElement1_MediaEnded"
              CurrentStateChanged="mediaElement1_CurrentStateChanged" />
<Button x:Name="AddToFav" Click="Button1_Click"
        Content="Add this video to Favorites" />
```

.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("path", out path))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
        {
            mediaElement1.Source = new Uri( path );
        }
    }
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // here must be somethink like:
    Button butsender = new Button();
    butsender = sender as Button;
    stack2.Children.Add(butsender);
    //better will be to save to Isolated Storage or somethink like this for future launching...
}
```

I have a lot of problems because I don't really get it how to perform that... I've tried to use global App Bar and allot more but unsuccesfully. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to follow the MVVM Pattern. You'll have a ViewModel class defined containing two lists.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Video> FavoriteVideos { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Videos = new ObservableCollection<Video>();
        FavoriteVideos = new ObservableCollection<Video>();
    }

    private Video selectedVideo;

    public Video SelectedVideo
    {
        get { return selectedVideo; }
        set { selectedVideo = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedVideo"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In App.xaml.cs you'll define the ViewModel

```
private static MainViewModel viewModel = null;
    public static MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
            if (viewModel == null)
                viewModel = new MainViewModel();

            return viewModel;
        }
    }
```

Then you can set the data context of both pages (MainPage and ther other) in the constructor like this:

```
DataContext = App.ViewModel;
```

Now you'll only have to bind the items to both lists (StackPanel won't do here. Use other listing like ListBox)

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Videos}"
ItemsSource="{Biding FavoriteVideos}"
```

For the navigation if you use ListBox just set the click event

```
ItemClick="ItemClick"


private void ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
        Video item = e.ClickedItem as Video;
        App.ViewModel.SelectedVideo = item;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PlayerPage.xaml,UriKind.Relative));
}
```

At the PlayerPage just bind to SelectedVideo and you're good. For favorite you just have to add the video to the FavoriteList

```
private void FavoriteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if(!App.ViewModel.FavoriteVideos.Contains(App.ViewModel.SelectedVideo)) {
         App.ViewModel.FavoriteVideos.Add(App.ViewModel.SelectedVideo);
     }
}
```

Now you can dynamically add data in your app if needed. StackPanel will only help with your static videos and it's not practical to use if the data changes.